# how to create "CassandraTableScanRDD" without sparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

i am working with spark streaming & cassandra connector, and i have some dao equivalent class (working with Scala).
on this dao, i want to create "CassandraTableScanRDD".
The problem is that i don't have sparkContext. and i cannot pass it over,
because it is not serializable.

here is a simple application which demonstrate the problem:

```
object Engine {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf()

        val checkpointDir: String = getCheckpointDirectory()
        val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDir, () => {

            val streamingContext:StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, batchDuration)
            streamingContext.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
            val dstreamsAvroEvents: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, Array[Byte]]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte]](
                streamingContext,
                PreferConsistent,
                Subscribe[String, Array[Byte]](topics, kafkaParams)
            )

            Algo.processStream(dstreamsAvroEvents.map(x=>x.value()))
        })      

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()

     }


}

object Algo {
    val dao   = new Dao(keyspace)

    def processStream(avroEvents:DStream[Array[Byte]]):Unit = {
        dao.findEntityBy(<somekey based on rdd>)
    }

}

class Dao {

  def getCassandraMappedTable():CassandraTableScanRDD[Entity] = {
    //========================================
    //HOW CAN I OBTAIN THE SPARK CONTEXT ???
    //========================================
    sparkContext.cassandraTable[Entity](keyspace, tableName)
  }

  def findEntityBy(someKey:String):FutureAction[Seq[Entity]] = {
    getCassandraMappedTable()
      .select(columnsNames: _*)
      .where(eq(Columns.SOME_KEY), someKey)
      .collectAsync()
  }

}
```

any idea how can i solve this issue ?

thanks,
Eran

Comment: You can't create an RDD without a SparkContext, period. Why do you need it serialized? Are you trying to create an RDD inside a transformation on another RDD? If so - that's (intentionally) impossible, your problem seems to be with the design

Comment: i am trying to execute Cassandra queries like in the following code: 'sparkContext.cassandraTable[SomeEntity](keyspace, tableName).select(columnsNames: _*)
      .where(eq(Columns.MY_KEY), somekey1)
      .collectAsync()'

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - you say "I cannot pass it [the SparkContext] over, because it is not serializable" - why does it have to be serializable - where is this code executed? If it's within another RDD transformation - as I wrote - that's impossible, and you might need to use something like `join`, but I can't tell without more context.

Comment: The code is executed as part of spark streaming application. During the analysis of the DStream input, i need to pull data from cassandra. i want to use "CassandraTableScanRDD". for that i need the sparkContext (see code example above). i cannot pass it around(as parameter in a function). i, just now, noticed that i can pull the sparkContext from an RDD (rdd.context), but i get an exception: "This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases...". So, what are my options ?

Comment: I think you should close this question and create a new one, showing some of your code and giving the information in the question itself.

Comment: i have update the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `SparkContext` using `@transient`, off the top of my head that should work.

```
class Dao(@transient context: SparkContext)  {
  ..
}
```

Comment: i use checkpoint. so when an RDD is recovered in spark streaming, it lacks the SparkContext. So, i dont have a place to pull from the SparkContext.